# SQL Server: Finding Nearest Location

Tags: sql-server

Given the following SQL which returns a list of airports based on a given city, how would I further enhance it to sort the results by what's nearest to me? It seems like it should be simple enough but it eludes me.

```
DECLARE @latRange float
DECLARE @LongRange float
DECLARE @LowLatitude float
DECLARE @HighLatitude float
DECLARE @LowLongitude float
DECLARE @HighLongitude float
DECLARE @Radius float = 100


DECLARE @istartlat float
DECLARE @istartlong float

Select @istartlat=Latitude, @istartlong=Longitude from Lookup where PlaceName = '"Franklin"' and StateCode = '"AR"'

Select @latRange = @Radius / ((6076 / 5280) * 60)
Select @LongRange = @Radius / (((COS((@istartlat * 3.14592653589 / 180)) * 6076.) / 5280. * 60))

Select @LowLatitude = @istartlat - @latRange
Select @HighLatitude = @istartlat + @latRange
Select @LowLongitude = @istartlong - @LongRange
Select @HighLongitude = @istartlong + @LongRange

Select a.City, a.State, a.AirportCode, a.AirportName, a.CountryCode
from PFM_Airport a
where (a.Latitude <= @HighLatitude) and (a.Latitude >= @LowLatitude) and (a.Longitude >= @LowLongitude)
and (a.Longitude <= @HighLongitude)
--and a.CountryCode in ('USA', 'CANADA')
order by a.Latitude, a.Longitude;
```

Comment: SQL has a pi constant, [`PI()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189512.aspx). You don't really need to hardcode it, unless you are intentionally rounding it to a particular value.

Comment: Does your version of SQL Server support geography spatial data types?

Comment: Currently the lat and long are stored as floats

Comment: Are your distances typically small enough and your airports far enough south that your longitude range approximations won't give incorrect results for northern Canada airports (as opposed to doing true great circle distances)?

Comment: distance maxes out at 100 miles

Comment: The reason I asked is that your calculation of @LongRange will give increasingly problematic results the closer you get to the pole, and your range 'rectangle' begins to look more recognizably like a trapezoid or pie slice. Great circle distances are a better way to go, although slower. You may be able to optimize by using the latitude range to restrict the airports you need to do the calculation for.

Answer (score 4):

@hatchet is right..  Assuming your instance of SQL Server support [geography spatial data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) then you should consider using that data type for the calculations, you also may find useful some of this code, just replace the table names, conditionals and pagination as needed:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NearestPOIReloaded]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LAT float,
    @LNG float,
    @DISTANCE int,
    @CURRENTPAGE Int,
    @PAGESIZE Int,
    @COUNT int OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

/*for pagination*/
SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Lugares as [L] WHERE dbo.DistanceBetween(@LAT, @LNG, [L].lat, [L].lng) < @DISTANCE)

/*paginated resultset*/
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by dbo.DistanceBetween(@LAT, @LNG, [L].lat, [L].lng) Asc) As [RowNum], dbo.DistanceBetween(@LAT, @LNG, [L].lat, [L].lng) as [distance], [L].*, [E].name as [empresaName], [U].userName as [userName]
FROM dbo.Lugares as [L], dbo.Empresas as [E], dbo.Usuarios as [U]
WHERE dbo.DistanceBetween(@LAT, @LNG, [L].lat, [L].lng) < @DISTANCE AND
[L].usuarioId = [U].id AND [L].empresaId = [E].id
)
AS ResultadoPaginado
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@CURRENTPAGE - 1) * @PAGESIZE + 1 AND @CURRENTPAGE * @PAGESIZE

END
```

this depends on a function called DistanceBetween (if your instance does not support spacial data type, then this is the part you must replace with a variation of your own code):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DistanceBetween] 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PIVOTE_LAT as float,
    @PIVOTE_LNG as float,
    @LAT as float,
    @LNG as float
)

returns real
as begin
declare @distance real;

declare @PIVOTE_POINT geography = geography::Point(@PIVOTE_LAT,@PIVOTE_LNG, 4326);
declare @POINT geography = geography::Point(@LAT,@LNG, 4326);

set @distance = @PIVOTE_POINT.STDistance(@POINT);
return (@distance);
end
```

Comment: If the OP doesn't have built in geography functions available, they can use this sql UDF: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=81360

Answer (score 2):

`how would I further enhance it to sort the results by what's nearest to me?`

I believe that in SQL Server 2000, to sort on a calculated value you must either duplicate the calculation in the ORDER BY clause `ORDER BY < the calculation>` or you can do this:

```
      select FOO.a, FOO.b, FOO.myvalue
      from
      (
      select a, b, <some calculation> as myvalue
      from T
      where <some calculation>  <= {some value}
      ) as FOO
      order by FOO.myvalue
```

P.S. But in later versions of SQL you can sort on a column alias.

In any case, you must have a column to contain the calculated distance.